# Using HttpContext outside of a Controller - Bad practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, httpcontext

I've been writing some logging services for my ASP.NET Core API.
I wrote a **middleware** that will log every action being called (cross-cutting concern, seemed logical).

One of the things I wanted to log is the user's IP (for instance).
The only way I could think of getting that data is through `HttpContext.Connection`.
It worked as expected.

[But lately I've been reading](http://www.strathweb.com/2016/12/accessing-httpcontext-outside-of-framework-components-in-asp-net-core/) some more about it and I understand that accessing `HttpContext` outside of the controller is considered a bad practice.
It makes the code not testable since it's very hard to mock and imitate.
Also, the code is not portable to other.NET applications and has to live in the context of the ASP.NET application.

So my question is - is it really such a bad practice using HttpContext outside of controllers - inside a middleware for instance?
And if so - what's the alternative?

Or maybe using `HttpContext` inside of components that will ever be used inside an ASP.NET (such as TOP-level controllers, or middleware) is legit.

Thanks.

Comment: It depends. If you reference it within your domain layer (=domain service), then it's definitely one of the worst things you can do, because domain must not have any dependencies on infrastructure (db, webservice, host like asp.net, wpf, uwp etc.). If it's used on application layer (=application service) it's okay. The difference is, application level is tied to the application and hardly or not portable at all (i.e. accessing the httpcontext information, it can't work on WPF since there is no httpcontext)

Comment: @Tseng, Yeah, thought so. That's why I asked if it's ok to use it in top level controllers and middlewares - meaning any code that has to live in the scope of ASP.Net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is totally fine to use an instance of an HttpContext class in ASP.NET core outside of an controller. Especially writing a middleware will be useless without an instance of `HttpContext` that represents the current request.

The main difference is that you should not use a **static accessor** like `HttpContext.Current` in the ASP.NET `System.Web` kind of thinking. Your referenced blog post is about how to mimick this back in ASP.NET Core if much of your existing code relies on this. In ASP.NET Core terms, an instance of the context is passed to your Invoke method of your middleware or you gain access to an `IHttpContextAccessor` object using dependency injection.

Have a look at this sample in the [ASP.NET Core Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware). The `HttpContext` is injected as a parameter names `context`, so there is no need to rely on a static accessor like `HttpContext.Current`. Especially this is easier to test, because you can create an own instance of `HttpContext` in your unit test and pass it to the `Invoke` method.

```
public class RequestCultureMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestCultureMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        var cultureQuery = context.Request.Query["culture"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cultureQuery))
        {
            var culture = new CultureInfo(cultureQuery);

            CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = culture;
            CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = culture;

        }

        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
        return this._next(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: As you said, I noticed that a `HttpContext` parameter is passed to the middleware, that's how I was able to get the client's remote IP address. I didn't notice the subtle difference between using an instance of `HttpContext` and using the static `HttpContext.Current`. So thanks for reassuring me.